# AWS Redshift column "view_table_B.cost" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have 2 queries in AWS Redshift, the queries target different table with similar schema. But my issue is that one of the query is working meanwhile the other is failed.

**First Query**

```
SELECT view_table_A.accountId, view_table_A.date, SUM(view_table_A.cost) as Cost 
FROM view_table_A
GROUP BY accountId, date
HAVING Cost >= '20'
```

[image]

**Second Query**

```
SELECT view_table_B.projectname, view_table_B.usagedate, sum(view_table_B.cost) as Cost 
FROM view_table_B 
GROUP BY projectname, usagedate 
HAVING Cost >= '20'
```

[image]

My problem is that the first query is working well meanwhile second query will return error as below

> Amazon Invalid operation: column "view_table_B .cost" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;

**Update-1**
I try to remove ' from the query but still get same result. And I attach the screenshot of query I tried to execute in redshift.

Comment: . . You have not correctly transcribed the queries.  If one works, the other should work as well.  As a note:  The single quotes around `20` are incorrect.  The comparison value should be a number, not a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for the reply. I tried to remove the single quote in the queries but still got same result. I also attach screenshot when I execute both queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift identifiers are case insensitive, therefore `cost` and `Cost` collide in your query.

I was able to reproduce the problem with:

```
with src(cost, dat) as (
    select 1, current_date
    union all
    select 2, current_date
)
SELECT
 dat,
 sum(s.cost) as Cost
FROM src s
GROUP BY dat
HAVING Cost = 3
;
```

it's giving me

> [2020-06-04 11:22:44] [42803][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: column "s.cost" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;

If you renamed the column to something distinct, that would fix the query:

```
with src(cost, dat) as (
    select 1, current_date
    union all
    select 2, current_date
)
SELECT
 dat,
 sum(s.cost) as sum_cost
FROM src s
GROUP BY dat
HAVING sum_cost = 3
;
```

I was also surprised to see that quoting identifiers with `"` *does not* solve the problem - as I initially expected.